# align tool on Arcview 3.2 Window Seven missing

Tags: arcview-3

after following the necessary procedure to install  arcview 3.2 on my windows seven...
I activated all extensions on including the spatial tool, make it as default, then applied. But i still got an error saying that some spatial... script is missing. hence i dont see the align tool on the toolbar.
i guess this tool is used to enter co-ordinate or georeferencing based on the online tutorial have been watching.
Pls how can i overcome this error

Comment: You can use 'Windows XP Mode' in Windows7 http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7

Comment: How you installed Arcview (and the extension) may make a difference  If your Windows 7 is 32 bit you could have used the Arcview installer by running it in compatibility mode and as an administrator.  You might try the same if the extension has an installer.  If it is 64 bit you probably had to copy the ESRI folder, the ESRI fonts and a few files in the user folder from a good install with the extension over to the new computer.

Comment: i copied the ESRI folder already installed on a Window XP, still yet i cant find the align tool